# Searchkick is not able to map the index to the model after upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5, searchkick

Working:
Environment:

- Rails 4.1
- Searchkick 2.3.2

I would perform the following query in Console:

```
res = Searchkick.search(
        "Thom",
        index_name: [Customer.searchkick_index.name, User.searchkick_index.name],
        match: :word_start,
        fields: [:first_name, :last_name, :name],
        limit: 10,
        #load: false,
        misspellings: {below: 3}
        )
```

res.hits looks like:

```
=> [
{"_index"=>"customers_production_20180830135206573", "_type"=>"customer", "_id"=>"162", "_score"=>66.72488}, 
{"_index"=>"customers_production_20180830135206573", "_type"=>"customer", "_id"=>"547", "_score"=>63.447693}, 
{"_index"=>"users_production_20170616114857320", "_type"=>"user", "_id"=>"447", "_score"=>59.895348}, 
{"_index"=>"users_production_20170616114857320", "_type"=>"user", "_id"=>"412", "_score"=>58.541008}, 
{"_index"=>"users_production_20170616114857320", "_type"=>"user", "_id"=>"338", "_score"=>57.721336}, 
{"_index"=>"users_production_20170616114857320", "_type"=>"user", "_id"=>"271", "_score"=>42.91793}, 
{"_index"=>"users_production_20170616114857320", "_type"=>"user", "_id"=>"315", "_score"=>42.91793}, 
{"_index"=>"users_production_20170616114857320", "_type"=>"user", "_id"=>"201", "_score"=>42.91793}
]
```

Everything works as expected. I type my term in the searchbox and I get my results.

```
res.first
 => #<Customer id: 162, field: yada-yada>
```

After upgrading to:

- Rails 5.2
- Searchkick 4.4.1

I do the same query I get the following hits back

res.hits:

```
[
{"_index"=>"customers_staging_20200920170910290", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"162", "_score"=>83.6008},       
{"_index"=>"customers_staging_20200920170910290", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"547", "_score"=>79.819855},       
{"_index"=>"users_staging_20200920175208885", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"412", "_score"=>79.099915},       
{"_index"=>"users_staging_20200920175208885", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"201", "_score"=>67.04228},       
{"_index"=>"users_staging_20200920175208885", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"315", "_score"=>67.04228},       
{"_index"=>"users_staging_20200920175208885", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"338", "_score"=>67.04228}
]

res.first
Searchkick::Error: Unknown model for index: customers_staging_20200920170910290
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/searchkick-4.4.1/lib/searchkick/results.rb:37:in `block in with_hit'
```

Here are my settings in the model:

```
include Elasticsearch::Model <-- Added after upgrade
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks <-- Added after upgrade
searchkick match: :word_start, searchable: [:name]
scope :search_import, -> {includes(:user)}
```

Can I get any help identifying why this is happening?

```
Searchkick::Error: Unknown model for index: customers_staging_20200920170910290
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/searchkick-4.4.1/lib/searchkick/results.rb:37:in `block in with_hit'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I found the issue.

In the docs:

Multiple Models
Search across multiple models with:

Searchkick.search "milk", models: [Product, Category]

so changing:

```
index_name: [Customer.searchkick_index.name, User.searchkick_index.name]
```

to

```
models: [Customer, User]
```

resolved my issue.